# Raspbian to Mint remote X session

Tags: raspberry-pi, xorg, linux-mint

I have Mint running in VMWare and I have Raspberry Pi 1 connected to LAN.

What do I have to do, to have Pi desktop (maybe in a window) on my Mint machine?

First of all which side has to be or should be/run the server (xorg) 
and which should be the client?

(Disclaimer: I am not especially good with Linux but I was thinking 
 since xorg is a server , implying operation over network, and Raspberry 
is most useful without a keyboard monitor etc... ,this should be possible 
and should be a thing.)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the term "server" in X11 jargon -- the "server" is the part the user interacts with, the part with the keyboard, screen, etc. A X11 "client" is a program that runs with its display on the server.

I would tentatively suggest that *probably* the easiest way to see the Linux desktop of a Pi is to install a VNC server on it, and use a VNC viewer to look at it. This will work where the remote (i.e., not on the Pi) user's system has any OS for which there is a VNC viewer (Linux, Windows, Mac, Android...). It's documented, in outline at least, here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/

It the user's machine is Linux, then it's possible to use the whole Linux installation as an X server, with its clients on the Pi. That is, you can use the Linux machine as a remote terminal for the Pi. In some circumstances this will be faster than using VNC, but it can be a bit of a nuisance to set up. Set up is not in any way specific to the Pi, and you'd probably get better information by asking in a Linux sysadmin forum.